# How to add two arrays together in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to add two arrays together. Why does the following how work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
 {   
        int sumvals[3];
        int nums[3];

        sumvals [0] = 1;
        sumvals [1] = 2;
        sumvals [2] = 3;


        for (i=0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
          sumvals[i] = sumvals[i] + numbs [i];
          cout << "the sum of the array elements is: " << sumvals << endl;

         }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "adding two arrays together"? For example, if I have {1, 2, 3} and I add this with {1, 1, 1}, should the result be {2, 3, 4} or should the result be 9? Or do you mean something more like {1, 2, 3} + 5 = {6, 7, 8}? Or {1, 2, 3, 4} = 10?

Answer (score 5):

First, your for loop is wrong.  Should be `i < 3`, not `<=`.

Second, you haven't initialized `nums[]`.

Third, your for loop is referencing a non-existent `numbs[]`.

Fourth, `i` is never declared.

Fifth, you're printing the result before you're done computing it.

Sixth, you're not computing a sum, actually.

---

I have a feeling this is closer to what you're trying to accomplish:

```
 int nums[3];
 int sumvals = 0;

 nums[0] = 1;
 nums[1] = 2;
 nums[2] = 3;

 for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
     sumvals += nums[i];
 }

 cout << "the sum of the array elements is: " << sumvals << endl;
```

---

If you're trying to add the values of two array elements and store them in an array, the syntax is as simple as:

```
arr1[i] = arr2[i] + arr3[i];
```

But this assumes that the arrays have been declared and `arr2` and `arr3` have been initialized.

Comment: and fifth you are printing the result before you're done computing it.

Comment: correct answer, but another question what about the negative reputation points. They are still active.

Comment: His question seems to be how to add the elements of two arrays together (i.e. `sum[i] = array1[i] + array2[i]`), not sum the elements of one array into a single value.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know that's how it's worded, and I'll include a snippet for showing that as well... but the code he has so far (specifically, his `cout`) seems to suggest my snippet is probably what he's aiming for.

Comment: At his level, I think I would trust his English more than his C++ to tell me his intentions, but who knows.

Comment: Yea, I was looking at his English in his `cout`, but it's a valid point, and with @Floris answer now posted, I'll leave mine as is.  One answer or the other is a perfect explanation for whatever it is he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sp whats the problem now sum to arrays together or sum each element of 2 array like a vector addition or what. Because i have just delete my memcpy answer. ;-). In any case you are right with your solution whatever the question was.

Comment: @ChristianSchack Your solution was about combining two arrays into one, right?  (I didn't look much into detail at it) The question is clearly about performing basic addition on the elements of the array.  We're just unclear if he wants a total sum of all the elements of a single array, or for an array to contain the sums of individual indexes.  If you feel your answer is an accurate interpretation of the body of the question (not just the title), undelete it...

Comment: ahh ok. Understand. One thing i have to mention either way is you have to be aware of an equal array size or at least check for this circumstance. The repu points i just got back. Thats intersting. Deleting a bad post means deleting the bad votes for it. So this conversation was usefull either way inspite of it not belongs the the current issue and also thread.

Answer (score 4):

When working with C++ for the first time, my suggestion is: forget everything that is C related and has a C++ counterpart. 
In this case stop using C-style arrays and use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead (the same can be done with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) but I'll leave it as exercise to reader).

Ok, you want to learn C++? Here's how your problem, of calculating the sum of all the elements of the arrays, can be solved in 3 lines of code using C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int, char**) {   
    std::array<int, 3> nums { 1, 2, 3 };
    int sumvals = std::accumulate(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), 0); 
    std::cout << "The sum of the array elements is: " << sumvals << std::endl;
}
```

The explanation is really simple: in the first line we are allocating an array of 3 elements of type `int` and initialize it with the three values `1, 2, 3`. Of course you can change those values to something else or initialize them like this:

```
std::array<int, 3> nums;
// ...
nums[0] = 1;
nums[1] = 2;
nums[2] = 3;
```

The most important thing to understand here, is that [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) act just like C-style arrays but they are more powerful and flexible to use.

In the second line we use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), a standard algorithm located in `<algorithm>` (who would have guessed) to calculate the sum of all the elements of a container (in our case `nums`). The algorithm is pretty simple and you can picture is as the equivalent of:

```
int init = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    init += nums[i];
return init;
```

for your own specific case. The only big difference it that it uses *iterators* instead. What are iterators? Well, that's something you'll have to research on your own. I can guarantee you there are plenty of articles and posts on the web that will explain it. I'd suggest you to start [from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), for example.

Just remember that [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) will retrieve the iterator to the first element of the array, and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) will calculate the iterator to the past-the-end element of the array. The use of those functions are pretty common with standard algorithms and you should get used to it. The general ideas of

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums), 0);
```

is

> Calculate the sum of all the elements of the container starting at `std::begin(nums)` and ending at (excluding) `std::end(nums)`, given an initial value of `0`.

As you can, see the function signature and parameters are pretty straight forward. And finally, in the last line, we print out our result (just like we you did before).

Comment: `std::accumulate` does not do what OP asked for; instead it generates a single sum of all the elements.

Answer (score 3):

Summing the elements of two arrays is done like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{   
    int sumvals[3] = {1, 2, 3};  // initialize one array
    int nums[3]    = {5, 6, 7};  // initialize the second array

    for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       sumvals[i] += nums [i];   // aggregate the sums into the first array
    }

    // print the result:
    std::cout << "The sum of the arrays is ";
    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cout << sumvals[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the others answers, if you want to *add two arrays together* and simply write `arr1 + arr2` or `arr1 += arr2`, I think these C++11 solutions are OK:

```
template<typename T, unsigned long N>
array<T, N>& operator+=(array<T, N>& thi, const array<T, N>& oth) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        thi.at(i) += oth.at(i);
    return thi;
}

template<typename T, unsigned long N>
array<T, N> operator+(const array<T, N>& a, const array<T, N>& b) {
    array<T, N> sum = a;
    sum += b;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int arr1[],int arr2[],int m,int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,size = 0;
    if(m>n)
      size = m;
    else
      size = n;
      cout<<size<<endl;
    int res[size] = {0};
    while(i<m||j<n)
    {
        res[k++] = ((i<m)?arr1[i++]:0) +( (j<n)?arr2[j++]:0);
    }
    for(k=0;k<size;k++)
     cout<<res[k]<<" ";

}
int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,5,6};
    int arr2[] = {3,4,1};
    int m,n;
    m = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    n = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    add(arr1,arr2,m,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.