# C++ getting the sum of two array

Tags: c++

i would like to get advised on how to get the sum of two array in C++. The sample problem is this.[sample problem and sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6xZ.png). I already got the first part however i can't get the sum. Please help thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int A[10];
int B[10];
int sum[10];
int x,z;
main()
{
cout<<"Enter elements for array A: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=9; x++) 
        cin>>A[x];
cout<<"Enter elements for array B: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=9; x++)
        cin>>B[x];

cout<<"New content of array A: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=9; x++)
        cout<<B[x]<<" ";
cout<<endl<<"New content of array B: "<<endl;
    for(x=0; x<=9; x++)
        cout<<A[x]<<" ";
        
cout<<endl<<"Sum: "<<A[x]+B[x]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example as described on [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That might also already solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add two arrays together in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579589/how-to-add-two-arrays-together-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) std::cout << A[i] + B[i] << "\n";
```

or if u want whole array you need to add both array into a variable using again loops if you are using c style arrays. After learning this try looking at c++ ways of doing this. this is c way of doing this.

Comment: fwiw the "c++ way" of adding two containers element-wise can be applied for c-arrays too.